# Apache Spark - How to split a joined dataset

Tags: python, join, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a joined dataset of (K, (V,W)) and I am trying to split it so that I can extract the (V,W) pair out of the dataset. I understand that I cannot split and/or strip the pair as the data type is tuple and not string. However, I haven't found a way to get around this.Can someone please tell me how this will be achieved?

If the dataset is called joined_dataset and it contains

```
(show, (channel,views))
```

this is my attempt in Python:

```
def extract_channel_views(joined_dataset):
    channel = joined_dataset[1]
    views =joined_dataset[1].split(",")  ?????
    return (channel,view)
```

Comment: The input and the required output is not clear. Please give an example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UPDATE

So - in pyspark I was trying to split the  pairs in my dataset where the key is the name of tv_show and the value containing (tv_channel, viewers). The sample input would look like this: ('PostModern_Cooking', ('DEF', 1038)).

The aim of my code is to split the pair into (tv_channel,viewers). In fact, I only needed to get the second element of my joined_dataset. My ideal output should then look like ('DEF', 1038). Since this is a composite value therefore the object type is tuple and nor string . Tuples cannot be split using strip and/or split functions.

I managed to write the below code that stores the second element of the dataset joind_dataset[1] into another RDD called channel_views. The new RDD itself is a list so I could simply split it up by calling the first and second items of this list channel_view[0] and channel_view[1]. So the code returns ('DEF', 1038).

```
def extract_channel_views(joined_dataset):
    channel_views = joined_dataset[1]
    channel = channel_views[0]
    views = channel_views[1]
    return (channel,views)
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10551616)

Comment: @greg-449 hope this helps now! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

def extract_channel_views(svc):
    return (svc[1][0], svc[1][1])

Then perform a map providing this function as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The following code takes the joined dataset - `(K, (V, W))` and retrieves two RDD's - `(K, V)` and `(K, W)`. I hope this is what you meant -

```
def extract_channel_views(joined_dataset):
    channel_views = joined_dataset.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0]))
    views = joined_dataset.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][1]))
    return (channel_views, views)
```

The idea is to use map function to map the key to the right value.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I intended to retrieve the (V,W) pair ;)